# Regarding logging into SQL*PLUS as sysdba versus regular user?

Tags: sql, oracle, virtualbox, sqlplus

I'm working the Oracle Developer days demo VM (virtualBox ),
and I can't seem to find the password for the SQL*plus, so I go ahead and log into it like so

```
sqlplus sys/sys_password as sysdba
```

I need to run some oracle memory management tests (REDO logs and creating archive logs, etc).

Is this a risky plan though? to use the sysdba user?

thanks

Comment: No risks here, sysdba actually have more rights than normal user.

Comment: As you can login using SYSDBA, just create a new user or reset the password for an existing one. You should ***NOT*** do your regular work as sysdba. Don't create your own tables in the SYS schema. This is like doing all your work as root all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just on a virtualbox vm I can't imagine any risk at all but it isn't best practice to operate as sysdba in a production environment (or any environment that you really care about).
Also all passwords for dev days are usually oracle.
You could always change them by going in as sysdba and executing:
`alter user system identified by "some_new_password";`

Answer (score 2):

The default password for all accounts in oracle developer day vm is 'oracle'. Best practice is , you can create dba account and use that account to do your oracle memory management tests. To create dba follow step 5 in following link 
http://praitheesh.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/oracle-developer-day-vm-how-to-use-pre.html

```
SQL> CREATE USER oracle_dba IDENTIFIED BY password$1;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT TO oracle_dba;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT DBA TO oracle_dba;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>; CREATE USER SNSDIA IDENTIFIED BY password$1;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT TO SNSDIA;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>ALTER USER SNSDIA QUOTA 100M ON USERS;

User altered.
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you shall face is .. if any one is able to acess that server
all they need to do is not even require the password .. of sys user and able to connect to the db try something like  abc(nonexistinguser)/fakepass as sysdba
you shall be suprised to see you still conected to database.